# How to write python sql output into CSV using a dataframe

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, csv, dataframe

IMPORT MODULES

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import csv
```

CREATE CONNECTION TO MICROSOFT SQL SERVER

```
msconn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}',
                        server='SERVER',
                        database='DATABASE', 
                        trusted_msconnection='yes')                                                                                                                
cursor = msconn.cursor()
```

CREATE VARIABLES THAT HOLD SQL STATEMENTS

```
SCRIPT = "SELECT * FROM TABLE"
```

PRINT DATA

```
cursor.execute(SCRIPT)
cursor.commit
for row in cursor:
    print (row)
```

WRITE ALL ROWS WITH COLUMN NAME TO CSV --- NEED HELP HERE

Answer (score 3):

### Pandas

Since pandas support direct import from an RDBMS with the name being called [read_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) you don't need to write this manually.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://user:pass@mydsn')
df = pd.read_sql(sql='SELECT * FROM ...', con=engine)
```

### The right tool: odo

From [odo docs](http://odo.pydata.org/en/latest/perf.html)

> Loading CSV files into databases is a solved problem. It’s a problem
>   that has been solved well. Instead of rolling our own loader every
>   time we need to do this and wasting computational resources, we should
>   use the native loaders in the database of our choosing.

And it works the other way round also.

```
from odo import odo

odo('mssql+pyodbc://user:pass@mydsn::tablename','myfile.csv')
```

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for. I am trying to write the sql output into a cvs file. Any idea how to to this?

Answer (score 2):

[@e4c5's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41650265/5741205) is great as it should be faster compared to `for loop + cursor` - i would extend it with saving result set to CSV:

```
...
pd.read_sql(sql='SELECT * FROM TABLE', con=msconn) \
  .to_csv('/path/to/file.csv', index=False)
```

if you want to read all rows (not specifying `WHERE` clause):

```
pd.read_sql_table('TABLE', con=msconn).to_csv('/path/to/file.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Much appreciated @MaxU .... but I am getting this error message: AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'from_sql'

Comment: that's my bad @claude, I linked to the correct documentation page by distractedly typed from_sql

Comment: @Claude, sorry, i just copied that part from e4c5's answer - it's fixed now

Comment: @Claude Where is the final solution?